# Save login to LocalStorge from Firebase.Auth (React, Firebase)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux, firebase-authentication, local-storage

I doing a login with `firebase`.
I got:

**login.js**

```
  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    dispatch(login(email, password))
    history.push('/shoplist')
  }
```

**userAction.js => login**

```
  const logUser = await firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  console.log(logUser.user)

  dispatch({
      type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
      payload: logUser.user,
  })

  localStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify(logUser.user))
```

**console.log(logUser.user)**
[image]

**shoplist.js**

```
const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin)
const { userInfo } = userLogin
console.log(userInfo.email)
```

But I'm getting errors:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'email')
```

When I reload the page then is fine.

**--Update**

userLoginReducer.js

```
export const userLoginReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case USER_LOGIN_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true }
    case USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, userInfo: action.payload}
    case USER_LOGIN_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload }
    case USER_LOGOUT:
      return {}
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

store.js

```
const reducer = combineReducers({
  userLogin: userLoginReducer,
})

const userInfoFromStorage = localStorage.getItem('userInfo') ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userInfo')) : null

const initialState = {
  userLogin: { userInfo: userInfoFromStorage },
}
```

Comment: I see that you save `userInfo` in localStorage, but in `shoplist` you are reading `userLogin` from REDUX STORE. these two aren't related to each other. can you show us the reducers and the way you create store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found clue how to do it:

Into **login.js** I added:

```
  const userLogin = useSelector((state) => state.userLogin)
  const { userInfo } = userLogin

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userInfo) {
      history.push('/shoplist')
    }
  }, [history, userInfo])

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    dispatch(login(email, password))
  }
```

**shoplist.js**

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if(userInfo && userInfo.email)
    {

    }else
    {
      history.push('/login')
    }
  }, [dispatch, history, userInfo])
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the error is originating from here :

```
 case USER_LOGIN_REQUEST:
  return { loading: true }
```

Once you request for login, the property `userInfo` is undefined in the state.

Try this:

```
    export const userLoginReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case USER_LOGIN_REQUEST:
      return {...state, loading: true }
    case USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, userInfo: action.payload}
    case USER_LOGIN_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload }
    case USER_LOGOUT:
      return {}
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

`userInfo` is changing in store based on actions, it can be `null`, `undefined` or data, you need to always check what type it is before doing things like this:

```
console.log(userInfo.email)
```

Comment: now into `shoplist.js` when I do `console.log(userInfo.email)` it displayed twice

Comment: @4est that's normal, because `userLogin` in state is changing and component re-renders.